# Best Way to Cache DB Lookup Tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, caching

I am looking to find the best way to cache the DB Lookup Tables which consists of about 75 table.

I want to cache these tables data to use them in my application so I won't open a connection with the DB each time I need them.

Here is what I am doing:

1. I have created a static class which contains static properties to each lookup table called `MyApplicationCache`.
2. In each property getter I am filling it with the intended data from DB.
3. I'm caching the data using `HttpRuntime.Cache["PropertyName"]`
4. Each time i **GET** this lookup table data I check if the `HttpRuntime.Cache["PropertyName"] != null`
5. If yes then I am getting it from cache else I am getting it from DB
6. Finally, I am invoking all properties at application start event in global.asax

Until now everything is good, but recently I've faced a performance issue and I can't solve it. If I wanted the cache object (Payer) to be updated from DB I am doing this:

```
MyApplicationCache.Payer = null;
```

This sets `HttpRuntime.Cache["Payer"] = null` so if I requested it again it reloads it from the DB.

```
list<payer> payerList = MyApplicationCache.Payer;
```

Now the Performance problem raises:

1. `PayerList` in DB are about 1700 record.
2. Each payer object has a `List` property called `PayerBranches` which requires looping on all `PayerList` List and getting `PayerBranches` for each `PayerList` item.

// MyApplicationCache Payer Property:

```
public static List<LDM.DataEntityTier.Payer> Payer {
    get {
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["Payer"] != null)
            return (List<LDM.DataEntityTier.Payer>)HttpRuntime.Cache["Payer"];

        // request item from its original source
        using (LDM.DataAccess.OracleManager OracleManager = new LDM.DataAccess.OracleManager()) {
            OracleManager.OpenConnection();
            List<LDM.DataEntityTier.Payer> result = new LDM.DataService.PayerService().GetPayersListWithFullName(3, OracleManager, "UTC");
            //List<LDM.DataEntityTier.Payer> result = new LDM.DataService.PayerService().GetListOfPayer("Order by Name asc", OracleManager ,"UTC");
            List<PayerBranches> payerBranchesList = new LDM.DataService.PayerBranchesService().GetListOfObject(OracleManager, "UTC");
            OracleManager.CloseConnection();
            foreach (Payer payerItem in result) {
                payerItem.PayerBranches = new List<PayerBranches>();
                foreach (PayerBranches item in payerBranchesList.FindAll(x => x.PayerID == payerItem.Id)) {
                    payerItem.PayerBranches.Add(item);
                }
            }
            // add item to cache 
            HttpRuntime.Cache["Payer"] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
    set {
        if (value == null) {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("Payer");
        }
    }
}
```

This problem occurs with each property that has a list in it

I don't know if there is a better way to cache data or if there is a problem in my code.

Is there is a better way to do caching?

Comment: What is the performance requirement for this solution? How much slower is it getting the data from the DB against the cache table(s)? if you have the right indexes on the DB, you may be better hitting the DB for every lookup instead of trying to load your memory with the cache objects...

Comment: 1- About Performance i want to get the optimal but now the page takes a lot of time to load these data from DB and put it in cache object a gain.
2- It takes a bout 70 seconds to load data again
3- Actually i am not fully aware about Right Indexes in DB
4- I am using these tables a lot of time in every page, I think caching  it will be better

Comment: Are you binding the full data to a control or controls? If you are using it only to do atomic operations, such as a grid to display the data but then operate on one row at a time, then round trips to the DB are still better and you will not get slow performance on your page loads. Can you explain a bit more how your data is used in your application?

Comment: - Yes i am using this cache to bind data to a controls (dropdownlist - gridview - etc.) and also for some business logic in each page.
- Okay the problem exists as i said when i am editing in one of those lookups in DB which requires from me to update cache object with latest values.
I am doing this by removing lookup table key from cache so when it is requested again it binds from DB.
- To be Honest with you my supervisor is not accepting round trip to the DB each time so i am trying to fix caching problem.

Comment: 1700 record is tiny, even if you are caching it. Why do you need to do two separate calls to the DB to get the Payer and PayerBranches data? I would recommend that you change it to one query and use a join. This way, you only perform one DB call and your data will contain both the Payer and PayerBranch info. Use a join in your database as it will be a lot more efficient than doing it in code. Finally, make sure you have the appropriate indexes on the database tables to ensure maximum efficiency.

Comment: In Payer object it represents a Payer Table in DB. PayerBranches Property is a partial property i added to the payer object and i needed it to be with each payer object. What if i had many partial properties in this object of type LIST as exists in (Services), I will get a complicated SQL Statement and in some cases it won't work. I 've tried Making one call to the DB Indeed But i faced a lot of problems which requires that looping.
I am Sorry for inconvenience But i am trying to reach the optimal performance